# Why get " expected selector for Objective-C method" Error

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
@class GADBannerView,GADRequest;

@interface BT_viewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, 
                                                ADBannerViewDelegate,
                                                UIAccelerometerDelegate,
                                                MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,
                                                MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,
                                                GADBannerViewDelegate>{
    BT_item *screenData;
    UIView *progressView;
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
    /* iAd Views */
    UIView *adView;
    ADBannerView *adBannerView;
    BOOL adBannerViewIsVisible;
    BOOL hasStatusBar;
    BOOL hasNavBar;
    BOOL hasToolBar;

}



@property (nonatomic, retain) BT_item *screenData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *progressView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *adView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ADBannerView *adBannerView;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL adBannerViewIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasStatusBar;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasNavBar;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasToolBar;

-(id)initWithScreenData:(BT_item *)theScreenData;


-(void)showProgress;
-(void)hideProgress;
-(void)navLeftTap;
-(void)navRightTap;
-(void)showAudioControls;
-(void)showAlert:(NSString *)theTitle theMessage:(NSString *)theMessage alertTag:(int)alertTag;
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

//iAd methods...
-(void)createAdBannerView;
-(void)resizeAdView;
-(void)showHideAdView;
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner;
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error;

//shake capture...
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

//message compose delegate methods...
-(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result;
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error;



//rotation methods...
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;

@property(nonatomic, strong) GADBannerView *bannerView;
- {GADRequest *}createRequest;

@end
```

I don't know why at this line:

```
- {GADRequest *}createRequest;
```

it gives an error:"expected selector for Objective-C method"
But if I remove some code above that lines it is ok.
Could you figure out what is the error here ? Sorry since I am newbie I quite confuse about the meaning of the error message.
Thank you.

Comment: You've used braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: I'm not saying this is your problem, but I've never seen the syntax `- {type *}selectorName;` before. Generally what I've seen is of the form `- (type *)selectorName;` (using parentheses instead of curly braces).

Comment: My bad! Yes, my eyes really got some problem. Thank you for recognising it. How can I mark your comment as my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are trying to declare an instance method. Change it as follows.

```
- (GADRequest *)createRequest; //To This

- {GADRequest *}createRequest; //From this
```

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer! The bracket is the problem here, thanks !